# How do random numbers from the random object work?

Tags: c#, object, random

if I have this:
(I already declared the variables)

```
random1 = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
```

When I have that, it'll generate a different number for every time I call console.writeline, so this would generate ex. 10, 55 and if you do it again 20,60 so basically random numbers each time, good.
But when I add this:

```
random2 = new Random();
Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 100));
Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 100));
```

Random1 will generate the same numbers as random! So it will be ex. 5,54,5,54 and if i do it again 70,34,70,34. But it's random2 is a new object so why is it generating the same numbers as random1??

Another example: 
If I have class like this

```
 class RandomNumber
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        public int getrandomnumber { get { return random.Next(1, 5); } }
    }
```

After doing this

```
randomnumberobject = new RandomNumber();
randomnumberobject2 = new RandomNumber();
Console.WriteLine(randomnumberobject.getrandomnumber);
Console.WriteLine(randomnumberobject2.getrandomnumber);
```

They'll generate a random number, but both of them will generate the exact same random number. So first time i'd get this 5,5 second time this 3,3 and so on.
But if I change the class to this

```
class RandomNumber
    {
        Random random;
        public int getrandomnumber { get { return random.Next(1, 5); } }
        public RandomNumber(Random random) { this.random = random; }
    }
```

And do this instead

```
   random = new Random();
   randomnumberobject = new RandomNumber(random);
   randomnumberobject2 = new RandomNumber(random);
   Console.WriteLine(randomnumberobject.getrandomnumber);
   Console.WriteLine(randomnumberobject2.getrandomnumber);
```

Suddenly, they both generate different random numbers! So why does this happen? What's the reason? Keep in mind, I'm still kind of a beginner.

Comment: Look at the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), specifically the second paragraph of the remarks section: "By default, the parameterless constructor of the Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close succession creates random number generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers"

Comment: Have look at seeding random numbers. It's all in there. There are times when you want the same sequence of random numbers every time and there are times when you don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see is "by design" - i.e. it happens because of how the class is implemented... the algorithm it uses needs a "seed" (kind of a starting state) which in this case is based on the clock... as documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx):

> The random number generation starts from a seed value. If the same
>   seed is used repeatedly, the same series of numbers is generated. One
>   way to produce different sequences is to make the seed value
>   time-dependent, thereby producing a different series with each new
>   instance of Random. By default, the parameterless constructor of the
>   Random class uses the system clock to generate its seed value, while
>   its parameterized constructor can take an Int32 value based on the
>   number of ticks in the current time. However, because the clock has
>   finite resolution, using the parameterless constructor to create
>   different Random objects in close succession creates random number
>   generators that produce identical sequences of random numbers. The
>   following example illustrates that two Random objects that are
>   instantiated in close succession generate an identical series of
>   random numbers.

This means basically that if two `Random` objects are created at nearly the same time using the parameterless constructor they will produce the same sequence of random numbers since they have been initialized with the same "starting state" based on the clock.

Comment: Sorry my internet went down. Can you clear this out for me? So let me get this straight, the third example won't work because even though it's two different objects of the same class, when you make a new object of the two of them at the same time, the "random" in the class for both objects will obtain the same "starting state"?

Comment: @CsharpFrustration yes exactly... you can change that by using the other contructor and supplying it with a different "seed" (i.e. starting state" which is just an Int32.

Answer (score 0):

Random number generation works based on a seed value in most of the programming languages. This seed is usually taken from a current time value. So if you declare the two Random objects close to each other, most likely they will obtain the same seed from the CLR. That's why they will generate the same numbers.

When you use the same instance, the first two numbers will already come from the random sequence, so the next two won't be the same.

Use the explicit seed in such situations (the constructor of Random which is overloaded with an int value).

Answer (score 0):

Because you are reseeding each time in the last example, if you don't reseed random object will pull from the same pool of random numbers each time.

```
        var random1 = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(random1.Next(1, 100));

        var random2 = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 100));
        Console.WriteLine(random2.Next(1, 100));
```